# Changing the value of a variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to build a simple scoring app but I'm running into a problem trying to keep it so I don't have to repeat a bunch of code to deal with each 'base' individually.

The basic idea is that when I click a button the script will;

1) grab the ID of said button

2) split the ID into two parts - (a) the bases name and (b) the button type (plus/minus)

3) if it's plus - add to the bases score, if it's minus - subtract from the bases score

4) update the assigned div with the new value

The part I'm stuck at is adding and subtracting. I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is the code:

```
$('.base button').click(function() {
    var b1Score = 0;
    var b2Score = 0;
    var b3Score = 0;
    var b4Score = 0;
    var b5Score = 0;

    var clickedButton = $(this).attr('id');
    var buttonInfo = clickedButton.split('-');
    var baseClicked = buttonInfo[0];
    var baseDirection = buttonInfo[1];

    var baseDiv = ('#' + baseClicked);

    console.log('You clicked ' + clickedButton + '.');

    if (baseDirection.indexOf('plus') >= 0) {
        console.log('Increasing ' + baseClicked + '!');

        ++;
        $(baseDiv).val();
    } else {
        console.log('Decreasing ' + baseClicked + '!');

        --;
        $(baseDiv).val();
    }
});
```

++; and --; are placeholders for where the adding and subtracting needs to happen. I just can't figure out how to get it to add or subtract from the correct value.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Make these changes. `var baseClicked = parseInt(buttonInfo[0]);` and while incrementing `++baseClicked` and similarly `--baseClicked` - `$(baseDiv).text(baseClicked);` (If baseDiv is a `<div>`)

Comment: `var baseDiv = ('#' + baseClicked)` should be `var baseDiv = $('#' + baseClicked)`

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` what is this look a like? would you able to post it too? ` bases score` what is it? the vars decalared above.

Comment: @shaunakde its probable says find the button in the `.base` class element.

Comment: Yes @Jai, right figured that out.

Comment: @OP are you interested in getting answer then you should respond to some questions asked by us?????

Comment: @shaunakde Thanks, but this didn't work. It returned NaN.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Mind if I ask why? I'm getting the output that I want from my version.

Comment: @Jai $(this).attr('id'); outputs 'b#-plus' or 'b#-minus' where # can be 1-5 depending on which one they clicked

Comment: To make it easier to read. Your code is short, but if it was longer, someone else (or even you) could get confused. It works fine because later on you do that: `$(baseDiv)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the scores an an Array object:

```
var scores = {
    "b1": 0,
    "b2": 0,
    // ...
}
```

Than you can increase them by doing the following:

```
scores[baseClicked] = scores[baseClicked] + 1;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I never thought to load the scores into an array and just work with them in there. Thanks!